# Enterprise Solr Library

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr

This should be a simple enough question, but I am unable to locate the answer.

What library does EE use for tying in to Solr? Is it a custom library? Is it based on the unmaintained library found at https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/ ? Maybe Solarium? PECL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at any file under `lib/Apache/Solr/`, you can see the license informaton at the start of the file:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2009, Conduit Internet Technologies, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * ....
 *
 * @copyright Copyright 2007-2009 Conduit Internet Technologies, Inc. (http://conduit-it.com)
 * @license New BSD (http://solr-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/COPYING)
 * @version $Id: Document.php 15 2009-08-04 17:53:08Z donovan.jimenez $
 *
 * @package Apache
 * @subpackage Solr
 * @author Donovan Jimenez <djimenez@conduit-it.com>
 */
```

The code is take from `http://solr-php-client.googlecode.com/` under New BSD license. So yes you are right, it's from solr-php-client googlecode.

Comment: I do not have access to an EE package, but judging by that version ID it is a quite old version of this library. Is that for EE 1.13?

Comment: Yes, it's 1.13 .. I have just checked version 1.10.0.2, it also have same license.

Comment: This is a bit of a let down. I'm really surprised to find they haven't bothered to update the library since 2009 (or switch to another that is still actively maintained).